# how to restrict user to only accessible the flutter app when user connect with organization wi-fi network?

Tags: flutter, dart, restriction, ip-restrictions, android-wifi-debugging

I want to develop a attendance flutter app in which want to restrict the user to access the app ,only when he/she connect with organization wi-fi network the user can access app. And if user try to connect with mobile data or another network the app should not open

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this plugin first

https://pub.dev/packages/network_info_plus

after that get the connected SSID, name IP, and ipv6 whatever you like, using this

```
var wifiName = await info.getWifiName(); // "FooNetwork"
var wifiBSSID = await info.getWifiBSSID(); // 11:22:33:44:55:66
var wifiIP = await info.getWifiIP(); // 192.168.1.43
var wifiIPv6 = await info.getWifiIPv6(); // 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334
var wifiSubmask = await info.getWifiSubmask(); // 255.255.255.0
var wifiBroadcast = await info.getWifiBroadcast(); // 192.168.1.255
var wifiGateway = await info.getWifiGatewayIP();
```

after that save the data and every time when you need to log in check the user is connected to the same SSID, or IP (below-selected item) that you already defined